# How to choose a specific line in a dataset using R

Tags: r

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXTE.png)

And I want to pick the row which the Date is 17/12/2006 and 18/12/2006, the type of Date is character, I use the code:

```
a<-c('17/12/2006','18/12/2006')
NewTable<-WholeTable[which($Date %in% a)]
```

The error is "Error in which$Date : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Then I try another code:

```
WholeTable$Date <- as.character(WholeTable$Date)
NewTable<-subset(WholeTable, Date == "17/12/2006"|Date == "18/12/2006")
```

It can create a new subset but with 0 rows.
Really confused

Comment: try `NewTable<-WholeTable[which(WholeTable$Date %in% a),]` note the comma after `)` to show we are selecting rows not columns.

Answer (score 0):

May be easier if you provide a minimum dataset, if I understand correctly though, this should work:

```
# In this example date is a factor variable with 4 levels
Wholetable <- data.frame(date = c("16/12/2006", "17/12/2006", "18/12/2006", "19/12/2006"), a = c(1:4))
Newtable <- subset(Wholetable, date == "17/12/2006" | date == "18/12/2006")
```

Comment: I uploaded a small dataset ,there is a link in the top